# How can I show the changelog of packages in DNF?

Tags: dnf

In Fedora, I was looking at my DNF updates list and wanted to see the changelog of a particular package set to be updated.

**In Fedora, how can you show the changelog of packages using DNF?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you answered your own question, but I came here looking for

```shell
sudo dnf updateinfo info
```

which is what one typically wants/needs to see new changelogs before `dnf` updating.

Comment: This is much nicer than the method I found!

Answer (score 6):

### Use the changelog plugin from dnf-plugins-core

```
sudo dnf install dnf-plugins-core
```

then

```
dnf changelog <options>
```